# Build app from python script on MacOS using py2app

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I did an extremely simple script to rename files from one folder to another:

```
import os
import tkFileDialog as tk
import glob

folder1 = tk.askdirectory(title='FOLDER1')
folder2 = tk.askdirectory(title='FOLDER2')

filetypes = ('*.txt', '*.mat')

myfiles = []

for files in filetypes:
    myfiles.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder1, files)))

folder2files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder2, '*.csv'))


for ind, t in enumerate(folder2files):
    os.rename(t, t.replace(t[0:-4], myfiles[ind][0:-4]))

exit()
```

The script works as expected. No problem there.

Just for the thrill of it, I'm then trying to make a standalone app with py2app for MacOS.

I created the following instructions, then edited the `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['myapp.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app = APP,
    data_files = DATA_FILES,
    options = {'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires = ['py2app'],
)
```

and then build the app with

```
$ python setup.py py2app -A
```

Unfortunately the program doesn't work and I am wondering if the problem lies on the `askdirectory` part of the script or I should have added some more information to the app bundle. Or, probably, I did something wrong...

I am not a programmer by any means and it's the first time I try to build an app, so I apologize if the question is poorly phrased.

After running the app it just says: "myapp error". Opening the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File                   "/Users/me/Documents/dist/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 376, in <module>
     _run()
    File "/Users/me/Documents/dist/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 370, in _run
     exec(compile(source, script, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
    File "/Users/me/Documents/myapp.py", line 6, in <module>
     folder1 = tk.askdirectory(title='FOLDER1')
    File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/tkFileDialog.py", line 178, in askdirectory
     return Directory(**options).show()
    File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/tkCommonDialog.py", line 44, in show
    w = Frame(self.master)
    File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2569, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
    File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2081, in __init__
     BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
    File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2056, in _setup
     _default_root = Tk()
    File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1814, in __init__
     self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
    _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
     /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5 /Users/me/Documents/dist/myapp.app/Contents/lib/tcl8.5 /Users/me/Documents/dist/myapp.app/lib/tcl8.5 /Users/me/Documents/dist/myapp.app/Contents/library /Users/me/Documents/dist/myapp.app/library /Users/me/Documents/dist/myapp.app/tcl8.5.18/library /Users/me/Documents/dist/tcl8.5.18/library
    This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
    myapp Error
    2015-11-24 23:18:27.017 myapp[3248:707] myapp Error
    com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[142] (org.pythonmac.unspecified.myapp.68496[3248]): Exited with code: 255
```